# Remove Metabox in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Does remove meta box restrict the permission of accessing this meta-box/meta-value

I'm trying to restrict access permission for editor role, there's a metabox permission which is out of editor's role. If I remove this metabox, does it restrict the permission for it? or just hiding it from displaying.

Comment: You're probably better off asking this question on the dedicated wordpress stack  exchange site

Comment: Do you mean, if an admin copies the code from the metabox, and pastes it into the dom in an editor level user's admin screen and submits, will it still submit? Depends if the person who wrote the code used nonces and checked them. Not showing the box doesn't automatically disable the code that is run when the post is saved.

Comment: @JasonB I see. Great thanks!